# How to pass upstream error response to downstream service using RestTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

I am not able to handle Error Response from one microservice to another.
Suppose service A calls service B.
**B returns :**

```
{
  "timestamp": "2020-04-18T13:02:30.543+0000",
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "Cannot find product with productId = 1",
  "path": "/products/quantity/1"
}
```

as body in `ResponseEntity`.
I have to fetch the same response message,status and error in A.
I am using `RestTemplate` to call B from A.

I tried

```
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

@Override
public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    return (clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR ||
            clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR
            );
}

@Override
public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
    if(clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == CLIENT_ERROR) {
        HttpStatus httpStatus = clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode();

    }
    else if(clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == SERVER_ERROR) {
        throw new RecordNotFoundException("Record Not found");
    }
}
```

But here I am only able to get `ResponseCode` and not the whole `ResponseBody`which contains error and message.

Comment: what you are looking for is here, you have 2 choices, handle with a try catch block or with an error handler. https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-boot-resttemplate-error-handling

Answer (score 0):

Your error handler should look like this:

```
public class RestTemplateResponseErrorHandler implements ResponseErrorHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean hasError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
        return (clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.CLIENT_ERROR
                || clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode().series() == HttpStatus.Series.SERVER_ERROR);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleError(ClientHttpResponse clientHttpResponse) throws IOException {
        HttpStatus statusCode = clientHttpResponse.getStatusCode();
        switch (statusCode.series()) {
            // handle client errors. Throw HttpClientErrorException
            // ex.getResponseBodyAsString();
            case CLIENT_ERROR:
                HttpClientErrorException ex = new HttpClientErrorException(statusCode,
                        clientHttpResponse.getStatusText(), clientHttpResponse.getHeaders(),
                        this.getResponseBody(clientHttpResponse), this.getCharset(clientHttpResponse));

                throw ex;
            case SERVER_ERROR:
                // handle server errors, may be the same as client errors, by throwing
                // HttpServerErrorException
                break;
            default:
                // default behavior for other errors
                throw new RestClientException("Some Exception message");
        }
    }

    private Charset getCharset(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        HttpHeaders headers = response.getHeaders();
        MediaType contentType = headers.getContentType();
        return contentType != null ? contentType.getCharset() : null;
    }

    private byte[] getResponseBody(ClientHttpResponse response) {
        byte[] result = new byte[0];
        try {
            // this is org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils class
            result = FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(response.getBody());
        } catch (IOException var3) {
            // Handle I/O exception
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then catch an exception and get a response by getResponseBodyAsString() method.

But if you have not public REST service, you may, I think, return application logic errors with status code 200. Create a base class for all responses with fields: errorCode, errorMessage, errorCause  (for example). Extends it by your REST response classes. And if everything ok - return a regular response with errorCode 0. But if you get an error while handle requests, return a response with some errorCode (not 0), and fill errorMessage and errorCause fields. This is not "Best practice", but sometimes may be comprehensive for you.

Comment: never return errors with status code 200, thats is bad practice. The status 200OK is reserved for that a request went well. Errors created by the client (client sending malformed data etc) should have one of the 4xx codes.

Server side errors should have 5xx status codes.

All 2xx codes are reserved for well executed requests.

And never make up own status codes like 0 that is extremely bad practice. Rest status codes are a standard, and should be followed for compatibility between services and frameworks so that people shouldn't have to implement custom handling of custom status codes.

Comment: you right, a recommendation about sending errors with code 200, is for not public REST services. I correct my answer.